# Make rvm switch to system ruby on osx

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I have a project that needs to use the system installed version of Ruby on OSX (1.8.7).  My default rvm ruby is set to 2.0.0p0 and I want to keep it that way.  Using RVM 1.19.6 (latest?)

From everything that I've read I should be able to simply create a .ruby-version file in my project directory and when I switch to that directory it should automatically switch to the system ruby.

According to the documentation I should be able to simply issue

`rvm --create --ruby-version use system@myproject`

and that should take care of everything.  This however gives me

`Unrecognized command line argument: 'rmvrc' ( see: 'rvm usage' )`

What am I doing wrong? Is the documentation out of date?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `.rvmrc` file in your project root, like:

```
echo 'rvm system@myproject --create' > .rvmrc
rvm reload
```

However I wouldn't recommend using system version, rvm installs the different ruby versions in its own directory and manages them easily. Alas system version is a bit outdated.

Comment: `system` - disables RVM control so it does not support gemsets - it will be ignored, to use gemsets with external rubies you need to mount them to rvm: `rvm mount /path/to/ruby` or to detect from `PATH`: `rvm automount`